# Can bootstrap be used to replace non-parametric tests?

Tags: nonparametric, bootstrap

I am fairly new to statistics. The concept of bootstrapping has been confusing to me.

I know that normality of the sampling distribution is required to use certain tests such as the t-test. In cases when the data are not normally distributed, by requesting "bootstrapping" in t-tests in SPSS would this circumvent the problem of non-normality? If so, is the t-statistic that is reported in the output based upon the bootstrapped sampling distribution?

Also, would this be a better test compared to using non-parametric tests like Mann-Whitney or Kruskal-Wallis in cases where I have non-normal data? In situations when the data are not normal and I am using bootstrap I would not report the t-statistic: right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The bootstrap works without needing assumptions like normality, but it can be highly variable when the sample size is small and the population is not normal.  So it can be better in the sense of the assumptions holding, but it is not better in all ways.

The bootstrap samples with replacement, permutation tests sample without replacement.  The Mann-Whitney and other nonparametric tests are actually special cases of the permutation test.  I actually prefer the permutation test here because you can specify a meaningful test statistic.

The decision on which test to use should be based on the question being answered and knowledge about the science leading to the data.  The Central Limit Theorem tells us that we can still get very good approximations from t-tests even when the population is not normal.  How good the approximations are depends on the shape of the population distribution (not the sample) and the sample size.  There are many cases where a t-test is still reasonable for smaller samples (and some cases where it is not good enough in very large samples).

Comment: Thanks that is helpful. So if I use bootstrapping then I would only report the p-value and CI without any test statistic, is this correct?

Comment: (+1) Would you by any chance have a reference or a link regarding Mann-Whitney and permutation tests? That's very interesting but not obvious to me!

Comment: (+1) Re preferring the permutation test, you can still choose a test statistic with the bootstrap, no? I.e. in permutation test version of $t$-test we might have difference of means as the test statistic. You could still use this in a non-parametric bootstrap couldn't you, such that you put bootstrap confidence intervals on the observed difference of means?

Comment: @GaëlLaurans The rank based tests are permutation tests of the relevant statistic based on the ranks. e.g. a Mann Whitney is a permutation test on the mean rank.

Comment: @JC22 You *should* report a test statistic (whatever statistic you bootstrap); a bootstrap test based on a mean will be different from one based on a trimmed mean, for example.

Comment: @GaëlLaurans For an example of generating the exact (permutation) distribution of the Wilcoxon rank-sum test statistic (equivalent to Mann-Whitney) and of the Kruskal-Wallis test statistic, see [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19429/1909).

Comment: @GaëlLaurans, on reference is: Different Outcomes of the Wilcoxon—Mann—Whitney Test from Different Statistics Packages
Reinhard Bergmann, John Ludbrook & Will P. J. M. Spooren

Journal: The American StatisticianVolume 54, Issue 1, February 2000, pages 72-77

Comment: The bootstrap is based on the central limit theorem, in some way, as a refinement upon it. So it can be used mostly when the CLT is relevant, and when the sample contains much information about what you are interested in!  When the sample do not contain much info, like about extremes, it do not work well, or at all.

Comment: @GregSnow Regarding the two last sentences - is there a way to check if the sample size and population distribution are suitable to perform a z-test? I often face situation with big sample sizes (100k+) but distributions are far from normal? 
I was thinking about bootstrapping to get a distribution of the mean and eyeball if it looks normal....

Comment: @mihagazvoda, using the bootstrap to explore the sampling distribution is a good tool to see if it is normal enough, but that still depends on how well the sample represents the population.  One of the potential problems is rare but large outliers.  Even with a large sample, very important parts of the tail of the distribution may not be represented (google for "black swan stock market" for one example).  Think about the science behind the data and how big of an outlier is possible, then to be cautious add a couple of outliers as large as possible, then bootstrap.